# Why does the python pexpect module fail in the flask module?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, pexpect

I have an app that I made with Flask. I published it with Gunicorn3. It has a module called python pexpect. To send command etc. to ubuntu terminal. I call a javascript code with this and get an internal server error. Strange thing is that, when I run the flask app python3 app.py without publishing it with gunicorn3, I write the same code here, this time everything works fine. But the site does not work if it is published. Does anyone know if it might be caused by Gunicorn3?
I do the same with netmiko module, it works but the waiting time is too much. So I want to use pexpect.

```
def botbaslatma():
    form=Guard(request.form)
    Guard=form.Guard.data
    if request.method =="POST" and form.validate():
            child = pexpect.spawn('screen -S idle node {}.js'.format(session["username"]))
            child.expect('App Code: ')
            child.sendline (Guard)
            child.expect('Logged in!')
            child.close()
            flash("Logged in","info")
            return redirect(url_for("kontrolpaneli",_external=True))
   return render_template("baslatma.html",form=form)
```

Comment: Pls fix the code you posted. It needs to be a valid code.

Comment: I couldn't share the whole code too long. this is the function in the whole code.